# Econding/char escaping on large SQL Statement in Python with Mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I was trying to perform a SQL statement and got some problems with encoding. After escaping and encoding it, it returns a Syntax error which I am not capable to identify.

The statement is formed by the following code:

```
dbquery = "INSERT INTO series (id,nombreSerie,imdbUrl,urlPoster,descripcionEs,descripcionEn,rating,episodiosEn,episodiosEs,estado,firstAired,airDay,Network) VALUES (" + t['gossip girl']['id']+ "," + t['gossip girl']['seriesname'] + ',http://imdb.com/title/' + t['gossip girl']['imdb_id'] + "," + t['gossip girl']['poster'] + "," + t['gossip girl']['overview'][:400] + "... ,"+ t['gossip girl']['overview'][:400] + "... ," + t['gossip girl']['rating'] + "," + total + "," + total + "," + t['gossip girl']['status'] + "," + t['gossip girl']['firstaired'] + "," + t['gossip girl']['airs_dayofweek'] + "," + t['gossip girl']['network']+")"
cursor.execute (MySQLdb.escape_string(dbquery))
```

Printing the execution returns the following:

```
print MySQLdb.escape_string(dbquery)
INSERT INTO series (id,nombreSerie,imdbUrl,urlPoster,descripcionEs,descripcionEn,rating,episodiosEn,episodiosEs,estado,firstAired,airDay,Network) VALUES (80547,Gossip Girl,http://imdb.com/title/tt0397442,http://www.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/80547-6.jpg,Gossip Girl satirizes and revolves around the lives of young Manhattan socialites growing up on New York City\'s Upper East Side who attend elite academic institutions while dealing with sex, drugs, jealousy, and other teenage issues.... ,Gossip Girl satirizes and revolves around the lives of young Manhattan socialites growing up on New York City\'s Upper East Side who attend eliteacademic institutions while dealing with sex, drugs, jealousy, and other teenage issues.... ,8.1,0x11|1x18|2x25|3x22|4x22|5x24|,0x11|1x18|2x25|3x22|4x22|5x24|,Continuing,2007-09-19,Monday,The CW)
```

And the error I get is this one:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in default errorhandler raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Girl,http://imdb.com/title/tt0397442,http://www.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/8054' at line 1")
```

I know that the commas on the big string may be affecting the sql syntax, but I have replaced the commas and it doesn't seem to affect the query execution.

Sorry if this is very simple, but I haven't found any answer on the web (maybe I am not searching well)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings have to have '' around them, you should have

```
Values (80547,'Gossip Girl','http://imdb.com/title/tt0397442,http://www.thetvdb.com/banners/posters/80547-6.jpg', etc
```

Comment: Thank you Niek de Klein! I was messing around with that, but I am not very used to write SQL Statements.